# Android. FireBase Cloud Message, не приходят оповещения когда приложение выключено

Tags: android, firebase

Всё работает, когда приложение активно или свёрнуто. Хочу сделать так чтобы оповещения работали и при выключенном приложении. Сделал по докам, не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Топик targetTopic существует и тестовое приложение на него подписано(иначе бы запрос, опубликованный ниже, не работал бы когда приложение активно)

**Запрос:**

```
{
  "to": "/topics/targetTopic",
  "data": {
    "title":"TestTitle",
    "post_id": "2"
  },
}
```

**CloudMessageService**

```
public class CloudMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "IDService";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "New token: " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String postId = data.get("post_id");
        Log.d(TAG, postId);
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                    remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),
                    postId);
        } else {
            String title = data.containsKey("title") ? data.get("title") : getString(R.string.push_title_default);
            String text = data.containsKey("text") ? data.get("text") : getString(R.string.push_text_default);
            showNotification(title, text, postId);
        }
    }

    public void showNotification(String title, String body, String postId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("post_id", Integer.valueOf(postId == null ? "0" : postId));

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_nav_menu_item_contacts)
                .setContentTitle((title == null || title.length() == 0) ? getString(R.string.push_title_default) : title)
                .setContentText((body == null || body.length() == 0) ? getString(R.string.push_title_default) : body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(101, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**CloudMessageInstanceIDService**

```
public class CloudMessageInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "IDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("targetTopic").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                String msg = "DONE";
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    msg = "FAILED";
                }
                Log.d(TAG, msg);
            }
        });

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        preferences.edit().putString("FirebaseToken", refreshedToken).apply();
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
        <service
            android:name=".service.CloudMessageService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".service.CloudMessageInstanceIDService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: А как вы приложение `выключаете`? Если `forceStop` делаете то работать не будет. Если смахиваете просто - то будет, но может зависеть от прошивки - некоторые могут тот же `forceStop` делать при этом.

Comment: Я не задумывался об этом. Вообще речь идёт о простом смахивании.

Comment: Попробуйте на других девайсах и версиях ОС. Возможно в этом дело. На первый взгляд код рабочий.